# jQuery Background Slider Functionality

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a background slider script work but it is just not working. Instead of the background to slide, the navigation icons are sliding in a weird way even though I want them stationary. At first I just wanted to remove the "1,2,3" from the slider navigation, but now the slider is just not working at all.

The CSS code for it is:

```
  #pictureSlider { }
  #pictureSlider div { height:100%; width:100%; position:absolute; z-index:-999; }

  /* NAVIGATION BOX */
  .navbox { width:150px; height:20px; position:absolute; left:0px; top:50px; }
  .navbox ul {position:absolute; right:10px; top:10px; }
  .navbox ul li { list-style: none; float: left; cursor:pointer; }
  .navbox ul li a { 
display:block; float:left; width:23px; height:25px; text-align:center;
background-image:url("../images/slide-circle-controls.png"); margin-left:5px;
text-decoration:none;
   }
  .navbox ul li a:hover { background-position:bottom; color:#000; } 

  .cam { }
  .clouds {  }
  .key { }
```

Thanks alot! :)

Comment: "cssclass" : "hb1", have checked this class name with yours is it correct???villa/js/script.js

Comment: the jquery creates classes dynamically for styling purposes I haven't used it in the code. Also, Any idea how to remove the "1,2,3" from the navigation?

Answer (score 0):

you could set the font-size to 0px, some browsers accept that and the 1,2,3 values won't be visible

you can also set the font-size to 1px and set the color to black, so the button's black border will hide the numbers

```
navbox ul li a { 
  display:block;
  float:left;
  width:23px;
  height:25px;
  text-align:center;
  background-image:url("../images/slide-circle-controls.png");
  margin-left:5px;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-size: 1px;
  color: #000;
}
```

but the best would be to modify the script to just don't put the index value, check line 59 on script.js:

```
.html(i)
```

replace it with something like

```
.html('')
```

and the numbers will be gone

if your slider is not working after your modifications just undo those modifications :P

Comment: Thanks...that works and the numbers are gone :)

Any idea why the script itself is not working?

Comment: try inspecting the the execution with firebug/chromesinspector/etc and see if it throws some error, anyway, the script looks like 'stolen' from some other place, just search for the original and then modify only that, i have no idea what you changed and what i looked like before